# Cyclic reference in maven multi module project. What can I do to fix it

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm doing a task where I should design a simple phonebook application divided into modules.

- phonebook-api: jaxb classes generated from xsd file, interfaces for repository, DAO and service.
- phonebook-server: it consists of implementations of repository, DAO and service. Also it has class for importing xml into database.
- phonebook-web: this module has all of the configuration needed for repositories, services etc. Also it has configuration for database. It has a few xml files which are used to generate DBI classes used in DAO and sql scripts to create a simple table to store contacts in phonebook database (it has only one table). In addition, this module has a simple controller.
- phonebook-client: simple MBeans application.

This is situation right now:

- phonebook-api module depends on phonebook-web, because it needs these DBI classes for DAO interface
- phonebook-server module depends on phonebook-api because it needs interfaces for repository, DAO, service. Also it depends on phonebook-web because of these generated DBI classes.
- phonebook-web module depends on both of these modules because they are needed for configuration.

So, there are cyclic reference. Can you please help me with this design problem?

Comment: If you intend by configuration the appContext.xml files, I recommand to work on seperating of config: create .xml conf files in each module to bound contexts. Otherwise, you need to review the need of modularity in this project.

Comment: Seperating the config needed to build the DBI objects is the best way to go as these are tightly binding your API and Web modules. have this configuration as a seperate module and generate the necessary files and add that as dependency to API.. anyways this API module is needed for Web .. these config dependency will automatically available for Web.

Comment: I need to use these modules, because they are predefined in a task. I'm new to Spring. So, my question is if I separate configuration, will everything still be collected in war? Only phonebook-web has war packaging. Also, I really don't know how to solve this problem with generated DBI classes. They are used in phonebook-api (DAO interface) and phonebook-server (DAO impl). Generating them in phonebook-server won't work because it will cause cyclic reference problem again (phonebook-server needs interfaces, phonebook-api needs DBI classes) . But I could generate this classes in phonebook-api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your question. The problem is with the design. The key to your solution is **assign distinct purposes to each module**, separate concerns and avoid mutual dependencies.

Other options you can explore include

- What seems like an anti-pattern here is that you have a dependency on a `web` module. This is unlikely to be ideal. You should avoid having module dependencies on units high up the stack. **This is what I would try to change first**: extract shared code from phonebook-web into one of the shared modules.
- Make smaller modules. Maven doesn't have a problem with that.

  If `a` depends on `b` for package `c`, and `b` depends on `a` for java package `d`, then you can extract packages `c` and `d` into a separate module on which both `a` and `b` have a dependency.
- Review whether you really need the separate modules.

  Maybe having `phonebook-api`, `phonebook-server`, and `phonebook-web` in separate modules isn't necessary after all. Unless you intend to reuse these modules in different applications, you may be better off using the single `phonebook-web` with all your current modules' code in it.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can only use these modules because they are predefined in task. I will think what can I do better. People suggested me to separate configuration. I will try it

Comment: Plus 1 for Review whether you really need the separate modules. :)